# Conditional rendering with every Update in text of search-field in a Todo List App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

I have a react To Do list and i display an array of components when the app is first loaded and whenever a user types in some string in search field i wish to make an **regex comparison and conditionally render** only those components that match....

My UI may give u a better idea, have a look...

[image: Screenshot of app on running npm start]

I wish that if i type `Al` only `Alomond` should be displayed and `Buy milk, Buy toast` should not show up...

[image: Screenshot of search ui]

Here is the code of my regex comparision...

> ```
> var searchRegex = new RegExp("/" + searchValue + "/gt");
>       console.log("--------------------------------", searchValue);
>
>       let tempitems = items.filter(
>         (item) => item.title.search(searchRegex) != -1
>       );
>       let tempdeletedItems = deletedItems.filter(
>         (item) => item.title.search(searchRegex) != -1
>       );
>       setContent(
>         <div>
>           {tempitems.map((item) => (
>             <ToDoPane
>               item={item}
>               delFunc={deleteItem}
>               done={addToDeletedItems}
>               edit={editItem}
>             />
>           ))}
>           <div className="doneWalaDiv">
>             {tempdeletedItems.map((item) => (
>               <ToDoPane
>                 item={item}
>                 delFunc={deleteFromDeletedItems}
>                 done={addItem}
>                 edit={editItem}
>                 type="checked"
>               />
>             ))}
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       );
> ```

***How can i Conditionally render the following code***

You Can View The Completete Base Component over here  https://pastebin.com/VWk0tEDq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [searchValue, setsearchValue] = React.useState("");
const handleChange = (val) => {
    setsearchValue(val);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    display(searchValue);
  }, [searchValue]);


  function display(searchValue) {
    if (searchValue === '') {
      return <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ToDoPane
          item={item}
          delFunc={deleteItem}
          done={addToDeletedItems}
          edit={editItem}
        />
      ))}
      <div className="doneWalaDiv">
        {deletedItems.map((item) => (
          <ToDoPane
            item={item}
            delFunc={deleteFromDeletedItems}
            done={addItem}
            edit={editItem}
            type="checked"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>;
    } else {
      // var searchRegex = new RegExp(searchValue);
      // searchRegex+='gi';
      // console.log('regex ye nikal ke aya h ',searchRegex);

      let tempitems = items.filter(
        (item) => item.title.search(searchValue)!=-1
      );
      let tempdeletedItems = deletedItems.filter(
        (item) => item.title.search(searchValue)!=-1
      );
      console.log('Ye sab filter hua saman h',tempitems,tempdeletedItems);
      return <div>
      {tempitems.map((item) => (
        <ToDoPane
          item={item}
          delFunc={deleteItem}
          done={addToDeletedItems}
          edit={editItem}
        />
      ))}
      <div className="doneWalaDiv">
        {tempdeletedItems.map((item) => (
          <ToDoPane
            item={item}
            delFunc={deleteFromDeletedItems}
            done={addItem}
            edit={editItem}
            type="checked"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>;
    }
  }
```

The code above can be used to conditionally render the function `display()` in the `return()` block of the React component.

Just make a simple JSX function call inside the `return` section of the return like this:

```
{display(searchValue)}
```

That's it. The `useEffect()` hook will automatically throw a call to React dom to re-render the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react state for the input and filter items based on the updated state, the code should look like this:

```js
export default function CentralPane() {
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            {items
               .filter(i => i.startsWith(textInput))
               .map(i => (<div></div>))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results inside the `render`.

If items is an array of strings, it should look like this.

```
export default function CentralPane() {
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(''); // the value of your input text

    return (
        <ul>
        {items.filter(item => item.match(searchValue)).map(filteredItem => (
            <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
        </ul>
    );
}
```